# Text box width defaults to being shorter than parent container width

Tags: html, css

The width of my child element (title-container) is smaller than the width of its parent (container). I want the child element to have the same width, but for some reason it defaults to being shorter.

I tried setting the width of the title-container to both 100% and auto but neither expand the content to fit the full width of it's parent container.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sixing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 45px;
  width: 46%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #faeeeb;
  padding: 60px;
}

.title-container {
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">

  <a href="#">
    <div class="image-container has-border">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-container">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="label-container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h1 class="title"><a href="#">The Issue With How We Talk About Self-Care</a></h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">How a mindful practice became a commodified wellness trend.</h2>
    <a href="#">
      <h5 class="cta-label">Read More</h5>
    </a>
  </div>

</article>
```

I want the width of the title-container to extend to fit the width of its parent container.

Comment: `title-container` is the same width (`100%`) **plus** `60px` of padding. It's not smaller, it's actually 60px *larger*. I'm not quite clear on what the desired result is. `box-sizing` is misspelled; perhaps that relates.

Comment: Exactly---a typo, Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Additionally, debugging CSS becomes *much* easier if you just right click the element you're curious about and go to **Inspect**. From there it was immediately obvious that you had an invalid property, as it was highlighted red and crossed out. It also highlights the elements, their padding, and their margins as different colors, making it easy to distinguish the cause of most issues.

Comment: For what its worth, I am often confused by how box model rules are being applied, and I often will add a 1px border in different colors to each contained and child. Adding red, blue, and green bdrs to your 3 declared classes in the order they appear, it becomes easy to at least visualize whats going on. From that i could see that making the padding of .title-container be '0', and changing the padding of .image-container to "padding: 60px 0" (so the padding only has a vertical affect) even's things up. Is it possible you intended to add the padding to the outside "container" class? Giuessing.

Answer (score 0):

So after taking a look at your code, I noticed that you have the .container set 46%, which would make it 46% of its parent's width. The .title-container was actually behaving correctly; it was also 46% wide.

The image in the container was showing outside of the container (no overflow:hidden), so it appeared as if the .container was larger than it actually was.

I've made a few adjustments below, which should give you the expected (visually) equal .container and .title-container.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #faeeeb;
  padding: 60px;
}

.title-container {
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">

  <a href="#">
    <div class="image-container has-border">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-container">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="label-container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h1 class="title"><a href="#">The Issue With How We Talk About Self-Care</a></h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">How a mindful practice became a commodified wellness trend.</h2>
    <a href="#">
      <h5 class="cta-label">Read More</h5>
    </a>
  </div>

</article>
```